# How to stop a logstash Config file running in Ubuntu?

Tags: elasticsearch, ubuntu-14.04, logstash, logstash-configuration, elastic-stack

Im running my logstash config file in Ubuntu using the following command.

```
/opt/logstash/bin/logstash -f /etc/logstash/conf.d/logstash.conf
```

Its working, However I recently realized that every time I run this command it starts another instance. Now I think there are six instances running. Because each new record i create shows as six in elasticsearch.

How can I stop all these other instances and is there any way to check how many are running?
Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the `pkill` command and specify the name of the process(es)  you want to kill

```
pkill logstash
```

Or the `killall` command works as well the same way

```
killall logstash
```

Comment: Noted, However I dont have access to the Ubuntu at the moment. Will get it soon though and will try this. Thanks a lot will let you know how it goes.

Comment: Agreed, though using the process name you save one step, i.e. you don't need to find all PIDs for all 6 processes.

Comment: thanks pkill logstash worked,
It wasnt straight forward though. Tried service logstash start/stop after pkill and it worked. Not sure what happened.
Is there any way to see how many pipelines are running?

Answer (score 1):

As Val states, pkill should work to resolve what you are facing.

To avoid this in future why don't you create a small service file so which uses a PID file so you can't have multiple instances running? Here is what I did:

http://www.logstashbook.com/code/3/logstash-central.init